# Navigation item - current date in url

Tags: menus, navigation

I need to create a navigation item with custom URL (Food) with url ([https://domain.com/food-menu/{current-date}](https://domain.com/food-menu/%7Bcurrent-date%7D). How can I do that ?

Comment: Lets assume you did it, are you going to create a page/post for every date from this point forward?

Comment: yes, it won't be static page but it is generated by plugin where I can set food menu for next 11 days